# Date field comparison, azure mobile services server-side javascript API

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have just started using Azure mobile services, and got stuck with relatively simple issue. Probably I'm doing something wrong...

I have a table with **date** field `scheduledFor` and from the server-side script I need to issue a query like "WHERE scheduledFor < SYSDATE".
I would really prefere using `Query.where(function)` method, I don't want to write SQL queries in javascript code. Can you advice how this can be done?

I've tried following:

```
tables.getTable('myTable').where(function(currDate) {
  return this.scheduledFor < currDate
}, new Date()).read({
  success: function(results) {
    // Do something
  }
})
```

and get `Error: Unsupported literal value Mon Mar 18 2013 18:07:06 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`

Then I tried to write:

```
tables.getTable('pushMessages').where(function(currDate) {
  return new Date(this.scheduledFor) < currDate
}, new Date()).read({
  success: function(results) {
    // Do something
  }
})
```

and get `Error: The expression 'new Date(this.scheduledFor)'' is not supported.`

It seems `where` function has a specific syntax, but I could not find documentation about it in MSDN.

Can you direct me, where can I read more about azure mobile services javascript API, and more specifically about Query object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have traced this behavior to an issue with the way we handle Date objects in queries. We are working on a fix. As a temporary workaround, is it possible to store your date as ticks in your table? You should be able to query against that without any issues.

Comment: Thank you Yavor. Your workaround will probably work, but we will need to change code in several places. So for now we will stick to using `mssql.query`.

Comment: Can I subscribe to that issue, or somehow get an update when it will be fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately our bug tracker for our server code is still internal. We do track our client SDK bugs publicly on GitHub, but we're not there yet for the server. I will try and update this topic when we have the fix deployed.